# Using .so in a jupyter notebook and google colab

Tags: python, c++, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, pybind11

I would like to import a library made with pybind11 in python in a jupyter notebook and a google colab.
the file i'm looking to import : "go.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" 
I can easily import it on a .py with "import go", but I can't do it so simply in a jupyter notebook (error when i try the 'import go' : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'go').

My original goal was to import it on a google colab notebook. but since that even in local it doesn't work I am first trying to understand what is going on.

I looked it over on google but I didn't find what I needed.
If someone more experience on that topic could help me, that would be great !

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

"go" is another library which you don't need i think
[goLibrary](https://pypi.org/project/go/)

> check this if it helps [pybind11](https://pypi.org/project/pybind11/)

you can install **pybind11** using following command

> **!pip install pybind11**

[here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable) is official reference for the same

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<absolute_path_to_your_so_file')
```

if it's on colab, then I think you will need to mount it from your drive and then look for the path on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank both of you.

@M_x i'm not sur I understand you're message. 
I compiled go with pybind11 indeed. it's about the Go game

@Vlad Sirbu, I did that on google colab before posting this msg, but still it didn't work

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
PROJ = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/..."
import sys
sys.path.append(PROJ)
```

still after i have the folder i can't import the lib. But i think that's a deeper issue because even in local it doesn't work.